# Optimization with rank constraint and a mask matrix

Tags: optimization, approximation, matlab, semidefinite-programming

I've been struggling with this optimization problem using Matlab, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it with Matlab, or at least which optimization method can solve it.

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \min_{A}
||(\hat{A}-A)\odot M||\substack F\\s.t. rank(A)=6
\end{equation}

M is a matrix of ones and zeros, the multiplication is pointwise.
So I need to find the closest matrix A to A_hat in Frobenius norm which have effect only where the elements of M are ones,
and with the constraint that rank(A) = 6

Comment: This is a rank constrained semidefinite program and it is difficult to solve in general. But there are some heuristics that you can find online.